# sharing a dictionary and an array among pool of processes

Tags: python, dictionary, python-multiprocessing

I have been trying to create a dictionary that will have a device mac id as key and information corresponding to that mac in a list.Something like this.

```
{00-00-0A-14-01-06:[['CMTS-51-55_10.20', '10.20.1.1', '342900', 'Cable6/0/0', '110', 'Cable6/0/0-upstream0', '129', 'Cable6/0/0-downstream', '00-00-0A-14-01-06', '10.20.1.6', '11', '1', '1424419744000', '692306', 'SignalingDown', '1', '118800000', '990000', '0', '0', '0', '342900'], 
['CMTS-51-55_10.20', '10.20.1.1', '343800', 'Cable6/0/0', '110', 'Cable6/0/0-upstream0', '129', 'Cable6/0/0-downstream', '00-00-0A-14-01-06', '10.20.1.6', '11', '1', '1424420644000', '692306', 'SignalingDown', '1', '118800000', '990000', '0', '0', '0', '343800'], 
['CMTS-51-55_10.20', '10.20.1.1', '342900', 'Cable6/0/0', '110', 'Cable6/0/0-upstream0', '129', 'Cable6/0/0-downstream', '00-00-0A-14-01-06', '10.20.1.6', '11', '1', '1424419744000', '377773', 'SignalingUp', '2', '118800000', '990000', '0', '0', '0', '342900']]}
```

These data values are retrieved from multiple files kept in multiple folder. One folder can have multiple files.

I am giving this list of folder to a pool of processes. So that within one process all the files from one folder get executed.

I am maintaining a local dictionary(collection.defaultdict) to populate it with complete information and then putting that information in shared dictionany(manager.dict) which i am giving as an argument to pool object.

also i am giving a character array to share some template information between the child processes and main process.

I am trying to check the sharing task in the multiprocessing part but i don't appear to get it working.

Kindly someone help me with it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/pypy

from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager ,Value, Array
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
import os

def info(title):
    print title
    print 'module name:', __name__
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print 'parent process:', os.getppid()
    print 'process id:', os.getpid()

def f(template,mydict):
    name = 'bob'
    info('function f')
    resultDeltaArray = collections.defaultdict(list)
    resultDeltaArray['b'].append("hi")
    resultDeltaArray['b'].append("bye")
    resultDeltaArray['c'].append("bye")
    resultDeltaArray['c'].append("bye")
    template = "name"
    print resultDeltaArray
    #print "templaate1", template
    for k,v in resultDeltaArray.viewitems():
        mydict[k] = v
    print 'hello', name
    #mydict = resultDeltaArray
    for k,v in mydict.items():
        print mydict[k]
        #del mydict[k]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    manager = Manager()
    mydict = manager.dict()
    template = Array('c',50)
    #mydict[''] = []
    #print mydict
    todopool = Pool(2)
    todopool.map_async(f, itertools.repeat(template),itertools.repeat(mydict))
    #print "hi"
    #p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',template,mydict))
    #p.start()
    #p.join()
    print mydict
    mydict.clear()
    print mydict

    print "template2", template
```

code is to check the multiprocessing part. It is not the actual implementation.
In this case it is just getting hung and not doing anything after printing:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 27301
process id: 27852
```

and when i try to interrupt the process using ctrl-C it again get stuck after printing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  Process PoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python    /2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python /2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 85, in worker
    self.run()
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 85, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    task = get()
  File "/home/pydev/checkouts/dev/trunk/thirdparty/pypy_2.1/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
```

Am I using things in a correct way? Does Pool object not allow multiprocessing array or manager.dict as an argument? Is there some other way of doing the same thing?

Comment: You never got around to asking your question.  We need to know what's happening, and why you think something _else_ should be happening...  preferably followed by a sentence that ends in a question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dicts (implemented as an in-memory hash table) aren't designed in a way that facilitates sharing between processes (which by their nature don't share memory).

Consider using threads which do have shared memory, perhaps using `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`.   Or use an alternative structure such as [*shelve*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) (a persistent, shareable data store).  Or use [*sqlite3*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) to have multiple processes accessing the same shared database.  Of install and use [*memcached*](http://memcached.org/) or some other shared data store that is designed to be shared across processes.

The docs also show how to use Queues and Pipes for sharing data across processes, but this likely isn't what you want (a shared key/value store): https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: When i use Process object things work just fine with shared dictionary. but when i use Pool things don't work. Is there a difference between child processes created using Process and Pool?